# How to match an apostrophe (') unless it is escaped (\')?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to construct a regular expression for this? If so, I'd appreciate if someone shows how.

Comment: Should it match `'` if it's preceded by an even number of \ symbols? (I.e. \ is frequently used to start escape sequences. Often, in such a case, \\ is the escape sequence for a literal \. And so, an even number of such means that the \ immediately before the `'` isn't starting an escape sequence - it's completing one)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: good point! It would be nice for the sake of completeness to account for this, but I don't think it's neccessary in my case.

Comment: It would be much easier to match the exact opposite: all characters except apostrophes, yet including escaped apostrophes. Would that be helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
(?<!\\)'
```

It means **match all apostrophe chars not preceeded by a backslash** (the backslash is escaped itself because it is a special char for regexps)

Comment: What if the string is `"\\'"`?

Comment: Eep, indeed. Sorry for the broken attempt (and more fiddling with broken comment syntax than the regex -.-)

Comment: @TimPietzcker: as you pointed out, my regexp will not work *as you intend* in that case. I only replied to the OP which was asking about a **regexp to match** `'` **not preceeded by** `\ `, I actually wasn't trying to implement a parser on-the-fly...

Comment: Sure, your answer is technically correct (for the question as it was originally asked), but when somebody has an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/136323), I find it nicer to actually solve `X` than `Y` :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker You are right, but I'm not (and neither are you) aware of what OP is actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I thought I did (because @VioletGiraffe said in a comment the goal was to escape apostrophes correctly. Apparently it isn't).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the .NET regex engine or another engine that can handle indefinite-length lookbehind assertions, then use

```
(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*)'
```

That makes sure that there is an even number of backslashes before the apostrophe.

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=        # Assert that the following regex matches before the current position:
 (?<!\\)    # No backslash before...
 (?:\\\\)*  # ... an even number of backslashes.
)           # (End of lookbehind assertion)
'           # Match an apostrophe.
```

If your regex engine can't handle that, you'll need to make the (even number of) backslashes part of the match and account for them later:

```
(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)'
```

Now `$1` (or `\1`) will contain the matched backslashes, so you can replace the result by `\1\\'` or `$1\\'`, depending on the details of the QRegExp implementation.

Comment: I'm using Qt (C++ library) and `QRegExp` class. Not sure whether it can handle it, will give it a try.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Unlikely. What do you intend to do with the match result?

Comment: All I want to do is escape apostrophes properly without writing a `for` loop by hand. Q: are backslashes escaped in your regexp already?