# Considering escaped quotes in an "all characters except" type regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to do some in-attribute JavaScript replacement to add custom JavaScript to the attribute. To be specific, to add a JS confirm() function around all of it. A rather hacky thing, but a thing I have to do regardless.

Here is the HTML tag I need to replace.

```html
<input type='submit' id='gform_submit_button_4' class='gform_button button' value='Send'  onclick='/* Lots of JS */' onkeypress='/* Lots of JS */' />
```

I have succeeded in doing it with the following PHP code.

```
$new_submit_html = $submit_html;
// __() is WordPress's function for internationalized text
$confirm_text = __("It will not be possible to modify your responses anymore if you continue.\\n\\nAre you sure you want to continue?", 'bonestheme');
$new_js_start = 'if( window.confirm("' . $confirm_text . '") ) { ';
$new_js_end = ' } else { event.preventDefault(); }';

$new_submit_html = preg_replace_callback( "/(onclick|onkeypress)(=')([^']*)(')/", function( $matches ) use( $new_js_start, $new_js_end ) {
    $return_val = $matches[1] . $matches[2] . $new_js_start . $matches[3] . $new_js_end . $matches[4];
    // (Other irrelevant manipulations)
    return $return_val;
}, $new_submit_html );

return $new_submit_html;
```

This works like a charm right now, because the JavaScript where I wrote "Lots of JS" just so happens not to contain `\'` -- escaped single quotes -- which it could definitely contain.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545811/how-to-match-an-apostrophe-unless-it-is-escaped), which would allow me to match the apostrophe unless it's escaped, but I'm not sure how to reverse it to match anything **but** an unescaped apostrophe. I imagine the solution will include lookbehinds, but I'm not sure how to proceed in this exact case.

Comment: It would be much more elegant to attach the handler properly using Javascript rather than an inline attribute, that way no escaping is necessary (see `addEventListener`)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Agreed (and that was my first reflex), but the only way I could find for this to work with this weirdly-coded plugin was play within its attribute-JS territory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to do this as it won't care about the actual contents of the attribute as long as they are already valid:

```
function wrap_js($js) {
    $confirm_text = "It will not be possible to modify your responses anymore if you continue.\\n\\nAre you sure you want to continue?";
    $new_js_start = 'if( window.confirm("' . $confirm_text . '") ) { ';
    $new_js_end = ' } else { event.preventDefault(); }';
    return $new_js_start . $js . $new_js_end;
}
$html = "<input type='submit' id='gform_submit_button_4' class='gform_button button' value='Envoyer'  onclick='/* Lots of JS */' onkeypress='/* Lots of JS */' />";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query("//input[@type='submit']") as $submit_input) {
    foreach (['onclick', 'onkeypress'] as $attribute) {
        if (($js = $submit_input->getAttribute($attribute)) != '') {
            $submit_input->setAttribute($attribute, wrap_js($js));
        }
    }
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<input type="submit"
       id="gform_submit_button_4"
       class="gform_button button" 
       value="Envoyer"
       onclick='if( window.confirm("It will not be possible to modify your responses anymore if you continue.\n\nAre you sure you want to continue?") ) { /* Lots of JS */ } else { event.preventDefault(); }'
       onkeypress='if( window.confirm("It will not be possible to modify your responses anymore if you continue.\n\nAre you sure you want to continue?") ) { /* Lots of JS */ } else { event.preventDefault(); }'
>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/DncpM)

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this. Great idea, and simply eliminates the worry of weird/complex regex.

Comment: @Ariane indeed. Most times I think of using regex to parse HTML I go and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1) :-)

Comment: If anyone tried the above and it messed up special characters, try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly